# Keycloak protocol mapper is not triggered

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

If I request for token from keycloak with Postman or RestTemplate then the Keycloak protocol mapper is triggered but if I request for token with the below code then I get the token but the Keycloak protocol mapper is not triggered.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizeRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;

private static final String CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID = "my-id";

private final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

public FeignClientConfiguration(AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager,
                                       ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    this.oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager = oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
    this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
}

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID);
    OAuthClientCredentialsFeignManager clientCredentialsFeignManager =
            new OAuthClientCredentialsFeignManager(oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, clientRegistration);
    return requestTemplate -> {
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + clientCredentialsFeignManager.getAccessToken());
    };
}
```

the application.yml has below entries

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-id:
            client-id: my-client-id
            client-secret: x43kka0-c9dc-1234-5678-31552f4dbb0c
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: http://localhost:10012/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the "working" requests made with (client-id, flow, realm)?